# How can I integrate proxies into my Selenium web scraper for True People Search?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am working on a web scraping project using Python and Selenium to extract data from the True People Search website. I have implemented the basic structure of the script, including CSV data handling and saving the scraped data. However, I need assistance in integrating the proxies and ensuring that the web scraping process runs smoothly without encountering errors or detection. Any guidance or suggestions on how to effectively use proxies with Selenium and handle potential errors would be greatly appreciated.

I am seeking advice or code suggestions that demonstrate how to:

Integrate 400 proxies into the Selenium script.
Randomly select a proxy for each scraping request.
Handle potential errors that may occur during the scraping process, such as IP blocking or rate limiting.
Optimize the script for efficient and reliable web scraping.

Comment: You do realize that you are asking more than one question. You should consider asking a question for each item: proxies, error handing (specific error per question), etc. Also, optimization questions are _typically_ out of scope in Stack Overflow. This site is normally for solving problems, not best practices. Depending on who view your question, you'll find that violating these rules will get your question downvoted and/or closed. I don't agree with that and have argued against this practice unsuccessfully. I am just giving you a heads up what to expect.

Comment: Also, because this question is so broad (multiple topics), it lacks sufficient details. Normally, you will have to show what you have tried (that didn't work) so that others can hep you better.

Comment: For example, you should always include version information.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly what do you need, that my method to use proxies with selenium.

1. Create py file with name 'extension.py'

Put that code on it ( That code create an extension of chrome to make connection with proxy automatic )
**extension.py :**

```
import zipfile
import random
import string

def random_string(letter_count, digit_count):  
    str1 = ''.join((random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for x in range(letter_count)))  
    str1 += ''.join((random.choice(string.digits) for x in range(digit_count)))  

    sam_list = list(str1) # it converts the string to list.  
    random.shuffle(sam_list) # It uses a random.shuffle() function to shuffle the string.  
    final_string = ''.join(sam_list)  
    return final_string  

def proxies(username, password, endpoint, port,path):
    manifest_json = """
    {
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "manifest_version": 2,
        "name": "Proxies",
        "permissions": [
            "proxy",
            "tabs",
            "unlimitedStorage",
            "storage",
            "<all_urls>",
            "webRequest",
            "webRequestBlocking"
        ],
        "background": {
            "scripts": ["background.js"]
        },
        "minimum_chrome_version":"22.0.0"
    }
    """

    background_js = """
    var config = {
            mode: "fixed_servers",
            rules: {
            singleProxy: {
                scheme: "http",
                host: "%s",
                port: parseInt(%s)
            },
            bypassList: ["localhost"]
            }
        };

    chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: "regular"}, function() {});

    function callbackFn(details) {
        return {
            authCredentials: {
                username: "%s",
                password: "%s"
            }
        };
    }

    chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
                callbackFn,
                {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
                ['blocking']
    );
    """ % (endpoint, port, username, password)

    extension = path+'_proxies_extension.zip'

    with zipfile.ZipFile(extension, 'w') as zp:
        zp.writestr("manifest.json", manifest_json)
        zp.writestr("background.js", background_js)

    return extension
```

**Main.py :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import selenium.webdriver
from extension import proxies
import random

# Open Proxies file
file = open('proxies.txt','r')
proxiesfile = file.readlines()
file.close()

chrome_options = selenium.webdriver.ChromeOptions()
proxy = proxiesfile[random.randrange(0,len(proxiesfile))].split(':') # Take random proxy
proxy_ip = proxy[0]
proxy_port = proxy[1]
proxy_user = proxy[2]
proxy_pass = proxy[3].replace('\n','')
proxies_extension = proxies(proxy_user, proxy_pass, proxy_ip, int(proxy_port),'Proxies/'+proxy_ip) # Create Proxy Extention
chrome_options.add_extension('Proxies/'+proxy_ip+'_proxies_extension.zip') # Add extention to chrome driver
link = "https://www.google.com/" # Your target website
driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)  
driver.get(link)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
# Your Scraping Code here
```

The Proxies file should be like this format : `proxyip:proxy_port:pruser:prpass` for Example : `123.21.32.100:8080:proxy_user:proxy_pass`

**You need to create folder with name 'Proxies' in the same code directory because proxies extension saved there**