# Python Selenium Undetected Chromedriver doesn't work with auth proxy

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, proxy

I use Undetected Chromedriver to bypass Cloudflare detection.

I trying force it to work with proxy, but unsuccessful.
First attempt (IP just doesn't change):

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
options = uc.ChromeOptions()
...
ip,port,username,password = proxy.split(':')   #proxy in format ip:port:username:password
options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server=http://{username}:{password}@{ip}:{port}')
driver = uc.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
driver.get('https://2ip.ru/')
```

Second attempt (with Selenium-Wire):

```
from seleniumwire import undetected_chromedriver as uc
...
ip,port,username,password = proxy.split(':')   #proxy in format ip:port:username:password
wire_options = {
        'proxy': {
            'http': f'http://{username}:{password}@{ip}:{port}', 
            'https': f'http://{username}:{password}@{ip}:{port}',
            'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1' # excludes
        }  
    }
driver = uc.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options,seleniumwire_options=wire_options)
driver.get('https://2ip.ru/')
```

Browser trying to connect with proxy, but I need to manually enter password and username.
I will be thanks, if you show me my mistakes or offer another decision of problem.

Comment: Try this way to use auth proxy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76396403/how-can-i-integrate-proxies-into-my-selenium-web-scraper-for-true-people-search/76400335#76400335

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After day of searches on the Internet, I found out that Chrome doesn't support basic proxy authentification. Thank [AbdeLhalimSB][1] for leading me to the [right solution][2]. But this and other similar solutions don't work for me because my browser refuses to load extensions from zip archive. So, I needed to change this code so that browser can load extension from folder.

extension.py:

```
import os
def proxies(username, password, endpoint, port,path):
    try:
        os.mkdir(path)
    except FileExistsError:
        pass
    manifest_json = """
    {
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "manifest_version": 2,
        "name": "Proxies",
        "permissions": [
            "proxy",
            "tabs",
            "unlimitedStorage",
            "storage",
            "<all_urls>",
            "webRequest",
            "webRequestBlocking"
        ],
        "background": {
            "scripts": ["background.js"]
        },
        "minimum_chrome_version":"22.0.0"
    }
    """

    background_js = """
    var config = {
            mode: "fixed_servers",
            rules: {
            singleProxy: {
                scheme: "http",
                host: "%s",
                port: parseInt(%s)
            },
            bypassList: ["localhost"]
            }
        };

    chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: "regular"}, function() {});

    function callbackFn(details) {
        return {
            authCredentials: {
                username: "%s",
                password: "%s"
            }
        };
    }

    chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
                callbackFn,
                {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
                ['blocking']
    );
    """ % (endpoint, port, username, password)

    with open(path+"\\manifest.json", 'w') as m_file:
        m_file.write(manifest_json)
    with open(path+"\\background.js", 'w') as b_file:
        b_file.write(background_js)
```

main.py:

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
import os
from extension import proxies
options = uc.ChromeOptions()
script_address = os.getcwd()
...
ip,port,username,password = proxy.split(':')   #proxy in format ip:port:username:password
proxies(username, password, ip, int(port),script_address+'\\Proxies\\'+ip)
options.add_argument('--load-extension='+script_address+'\\Proxies\\'+ip)
driver = uc.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
```

Note, this solution will work in headless mode, but not in incognito mode.
[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/users/20112601/abdelhalimsb
[2]: [How can I integrate proxies into my Selenium web scraper for True People Search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76396403/how-can-i-integrate-proxies-into-my-selenium-web-scraper-for-true-people-search/76400335#76400335)

Answer (score 0):

[SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) has a special undetected-chromedriver mode that lets you set the proxy settings via method arg (or on the command-line).

`pip install seleniumbase`, then run with `python` after you fill in the proxy settings on the `SB()` call:

```py
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(uc=True, pls="none", proxy="USER:PASS@HOST:PORT") as sb:
    sb.open("https://nowsecure.nl/#relax")
    sb.assert_text("OH YEAH, you passed!", "h1")
    sb.post_message("Selenium wasn't detected!")
```

It sets `uc` to True (to enabled undetected-chromedriver mode), it sets `pls` to "none" (a different pageLoadStrategy might freeze up proxy tests in that mode), and it sets the `proxy` settings (after you fill in the one you want).

Comment: I tried this too, but had no effect for me: Chrome still forced me to manually enter password and username.